# Raspberry Pi: MongoError: Server at localhost:27017 reports wire version 0, but this version of Node.js Driver requires at least 2 (MongoDB2.6)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, raspberry-pi

i try to set up a MongoDB and get a connection to the Database with Node.js.
I am currently working with a Raspberry Pi 2. And the MongoDB Version= 2.4.

If I try to execute this code:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; 
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

I am getting this error:
MongoError: Server at localhost:27017 reports wire version 0, but this version of Node.js Driver requires at least 2 (MongoDB2.6).

And the Database looks like this:
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aa1719e551ea6f4212f71c2"), "numer" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5aa1805aa17e0c953e4ec284"), "numer" : 1, "name" : "test" }

Maybe it is the Version of the Pi. But there must be other opportunities to do it.
Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a version compatibility issue between your node driver and your database. MongoDB 2.4 is rather old; [recent versions](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/driver-compatibility-reference/#node-js-driver-compatibility) of the node driver likely don't support versions earlier than MongoDB 2.6.

Trying updating to use a more recent version of MongoDB; MongoDB 2.4 is well past [end-of-life](https://www.mongodb.com/support-policy).

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded my mongo DB version from 2.4.9 to 3.4.15 to resolve this issue. It works for me after version update.

Comment: I am curious how you upgraded to 3.4.15. AFAIK, it requires 64-bit and RPi runs on 32-bit.

Comment: Raspbian is a 32-bit distro; you need to run a 64-bit distro (eg [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi-2-3)) on a Pi that has an arm64 CPU -- Pi ≥ 3.

Comment: @josh3736 There are no Pis that have 64bit CPUs at the moment.

Comment: @user11909 That seems wrong, f.e. Raspberry Pi 3 Model B was released in February 2016 with a 1.2 GHz 64-bit quad core cpu. What do you mean with "at the moment"?

Comment: @wonkorealtime "at the moment" = date of  my comment. I was misinformed at that time as it seems

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers.

I found a workaround with docker on the raspberry pi.

For that, I installed hypriot (docker optimized pi os) on the pi and then I started a MongoDB docker container.

For more information: https://blog.hypriot.com/getting-started-with-docker-on-your-arm-device/

Comment: Can you explain how you slove this. In the link mongodb isn't mentioned.